# Rewrite matrix into rules

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I have a lot of rectangular matrices where each cell represents some outcome. As matrices are difficult to maintain, it is my goal to rewrite all of them into rules.

Example Matrix 1:

[image]

This is easy to turn into rules (pseudocode):

```
if (i <= 5 and j <=3) then A
else if (i <= 5 and j >=4) then B
else C
```

How do I rewrite the following matrix?

[image]

Plain text:

```
ij  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   A   A   A   A   C   C   C   C   B
2   A   A   A   C   C   C   C   B   B
3   A   A   C   C   C   C   B   B   B
4   A   C   C   C   C   B   B   B   B
5   C   C   C   C   B   B   B   B   B
6   C   C   C   B   B   B   B   B   B
7   C   C   B   B   B   B   B   B   B
8   C   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B
9   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second matrix can be represented as:

```
if (i+j <= 5)
    return A;
else if (i+j <= 9)
    return C;
else 
    return B;
```

In general, you can check which side of a diagonal line a point is on by testing `i+j` for a `/` line, or `i-j` for a `\` line.